# Is there a way to stop this error "select * from "client_api_key" where "api_key" = $1 limit $2 - Connection terminated unexpectedly"

Tags: postgresql, render, knex.js, adonis.js

Im using adonis.js , I have the following query... When I make a request to my API this is the first database query. I get the above error only once every hour or so. Im using render.com to host my API and postgres database. I believe adonis.js uses knex and this maybe the problem but I am not sure.

```
const api_key_check = await database
  .table('client_api_key')
  .where('api_key', api_key_encoded)
  .first()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like knex have an open issue since node's 12 release.
Follow this thread and see if some proposed solution works for you:

https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/3523#issuecomment-722574083